# How to use queryTransaction() method in hyperledger 1.4?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to fetch data using transaction ID in 1.4 using queryTransaction() method of Channel class.
But it does not identify the method. Am i missing code snippets?

Below is the code i am using;

```
/*
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

'use strict';

const { FileSystemWallet, Gateway } = require('fabric-network');
const path = require('path');

const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'first-network', 'connection-org1.json');

async function main() {
    try {

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
        const userExists = await wallet.exists('user1');
        if (!userExists) {
            console.log('An identity for the user "user1" does not exist in the wallet');
            console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
            return;
        }

        // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
        const gateway = new Gateway();
        await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });

        // Get the network (channel) our contract is deployed to.
        const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');

        // Get the contract from the network.
        const contract = network.getContract('fabcar');

        // Evaluate the specified transaction.

        const result = await network .queryTransaction('3c185a9409cc001179d4646fdd28db52174b0f45ae58c133de53f5147a5b5e7f');

        console.log(`Transaction has been evaluated, result is: ${result.toString()}`);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to evaluate transaction: ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say `queryTransaction` is a method from `Channel`class, but you are trying to call it from `Network` class (really from nothing, as you have an space). Use `getClient` from `Gateway`, then `getChannel` from `Client` and then `queryTransaction`.

- https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/module-fabric-network.Gateway.html#getClient__anchor
- https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/Client.html#getChannel__anchor
- https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/Channel.html#queryTransaction__anchor

Comment: It worked as suggested by @kekomal  on using below codes:

const client = gateway.getClient();
        const channel = client.getChannel('mychannel');
        const result = await channel.queryTransaction('b660bafec6cd173c5f6e5f521ed61a7547db0fa9a6383d60a275c4606cd31928');

It gives a lot of data when converting buffer into JSON. How should i filter only the actual transaction data (state) returned by queryTransaction() method?

Comment: Ah...! If you want to get the state you should preferably provide an operation in your chaincode to query the state DB and query that operation from your client using `Contract.evaluateTransaction`. `Channel.queryTransaction` is designed for fine-grained transaction inspection. https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/module-fabric-network.Contract.html#evaluateTransaction__anchor